# List records in table A with only one relation in table B, and has a relation in table C

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
ITEMS       ITEM_FILES_MAP     FILES
id          id                 id
name        item_id            filename
in_trash    file_id
```

FILES has a one to many relationship with ITEMS trough the ITEM_FILES_MAP table.

I need a select query that returns a list of files by the following critera:

- Only return files related to items where in_trash = 1
- Avoid files that are related to items where in_trash = 0

Example:

```
ITEMS
id     name     in_trash
1      Item A   0
2      Item B   0
3      Item C   1
4      Item D   1

FILES
id     filename
1      File A
2      File B
3      File C
4      File D
5      File E

ITEM_FILES_MAP
id     item_id  file_id
1      1        2
2      1        3
3      2        1
4      3        2
5      3        4
6      4        3
7      4        4
```

*Desired result:*
Returns File D (id 4).

File B, C and D (id 2,3,4 in FILES table) is due to be returned, but because File B and C are related to items where in_trash = 0, they will not be listed.

Here is a sample dump if you want to test out solutions:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `files` (`id`, `filename`)
VALUES
    (1,'File A'),
    (2,'File B'),
    (3,'File C'),
    (4,'File D'),
    (5,'File E');

CREATE TABLE `item_files_map` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `item_files_map` (`id`, `item_id`, `file_id`)
VALUES
    (1,1,2),
    (2,1,3),
    (3,2,1),
    (4,3,2),
    (5,3,4),
    (6,4,3),
    (7,4,4);

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_trash` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `name`, `in_trash`)
VALUES
    (1,'Item A',0),
    (2,'Item B',0),
    (3,'Item C',1),
    (4,'Item D',1);
```

Comment: Oops, my query was wrong, indeed. I deleted the answer.

Comment: I added another answer, thoroughly tested this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preparations

First, make sure you have an `UNIQUE INDEX` on fields `item_id` and `file_id` (in this order) on table `item_files_map`. No matter what query you run, if it includes this table the index will make the things fly instead or crawl. *On some queries, however, an index having the fields in the opposite order would help more but for this task we need them in the presented order.*

```
ALTER TABLE item_files_map
ADD UNIQUE INDEX item_file_id(`item_id`, `file_id`);
```

Also make sure you have an `INDEX` on `items`.`in_trash`.

```
ALTER TABLE items
ADD INDEX (`in_trash`);
```

For large tables it's possible that MySQL will ignore it if the ratio between `1` and `0` values is somewhere between 0.05 and 20 (if none of the values is used on less than 5% of the rows).

Probably the items having `in_trash=1` are much fewer than those having `in_trash=0` (or vice-versa) and this will convince MySQL to use the index for one of the instances of table `items` because the index removes a lot of rows from examination.

More, because the queries use only the fields `PK` and `in_trash` from this table, MySQL will use the index to get the information it needs and will not read the table data. And since the index is smaller than the table data, reading less bytes from the storage improves the execution speed.

#### The query, first attempt (following all the requirements)

A query that does what you need is:

```
# Query #1

SELECT DISTINCT f.id, f.filename
FROM items iit1
  INNER JOIN item_files_map ifm1 ON iit1.id = ifm1.item_id
  INNER JOIN files f ON f.id = ifm1.file_id
WHERE iit1.in_trash = 1
  AND ifm1.file_id NOT IN (
    SELECT ff.id
    FROM files ff
      INNER JOIN item_files_map ifm0 ON ff.id = ifm0.file_id
      INNER JOIN items iit0 ON iit0.id = ifm0.item_id
    WHERE iit0.in_trash = 0
  );
```

#### Improving the query by slimming it

This query is not as good as can get and it can be improved if you are absolutely sure that table `item_files_map` does not contain orphan `file_id` values (i.e. values that cannot be found in column `files`.`id`). This should not happen on a well designed application and the database can help you avoid such situations by using [FOREIGN KEY constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) (on InnoDB only).

Assuming this condition is met, we can remove table `files` from the inner query, making it simpler and faster:

```
# Query #2

SELECT DISTINCT f.id, f.filename
FROM items iit1
  INNER JOIN item_files_map ifm1 ON iit1.id = ifm1.item_id
  INNER JOIN files f ON f.id = ifm1.file_id
WHERE iit1.in_trash = 1
  AND ifm1.file_id NOT IN (
    SELECT ifm0.file_id
    FROM item_files_map ifm0
      INNER JOIN items iit0 ON iit0.id = ifm0.item_id
    WHERE iit0.in_trash = 0
  );
```

This query will produce the correct results.

#### The final query (ignore some of the requirements but produces correct results)

Another optimization can be done by selecting only the `file`.`id` and get rid of the filename for now, will run another query to get it:

```
# Query #3

SELECT DISTINCT ifm1.file_id
FROM items iit1 
  INNER JOIN item_files_map ifm1 ON iit1.id = ifm1.item_id
WHERE iit1.in_trash = 1
  AND ifm1.file_id NOT IN (
    SELECT ifm0.file_id
    FROM item_files_map ifm0
      INNER JOIN items iit0 ON iit0.id = ifm0.item_id
    WHERE iit0.in_trash = 0
  );
```

You can change the last `JOIN` to:

```
      INNER JOIN items iit0 FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) ON iit0.id = ifm0.item_id
```

to force MySQL use the `PK` for that join but I cannot tell if it will run faster. Maybe when the table becomes bigger.

This query doesn't select the filename (because it doesn't access the `files` table at all). It can be easily fetched (together with other fields from table `files` or with fields selected from other joined tables) using a query that runs like the wind because it uses the table's `PK` to get the rows it needs:

```
# Query #3-extra

SELECT *
FROM files
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Replace `1, 2, 3` with the list of file IDs returned by the previous query.

For big tables, these two queries could run faster than `Query #2`

#### Remark

As explained in the previous section, `Query #2` and `Query #3` assume there are no orphan `file_id` entries in the `item_files_map` table. If such orphan entries exist `Query #3` can return invalid `file_id` values but they will be filtered out by `Query #3-extra` and the final result set returned by it will contain only valid results.

Comment: Thank you very much for good explanations and great tips for performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test in mysql but you could do something like this :

```
SELECT filename FROM
 (SELECT filename, sum(in_trash) AS s, count(*) AS c 
  FROM items, files, item_files_map 
  WHERE items.id = item_files_map.item_id AND files.id = item_files_map.file_id 
  GROUP BY filename) sub 
WHERE s = c
```

The subquery computes for each filename the count of items referencing it and the count of items in trash. For your example it returns :

```
"D"   2   2
"B"   1   2
"C"   1   2
"A"   0   1
```

If these counts are the same then only in trash items reference.

EDIT: Following the suggestions of axiac, here is the query:

```
SELECT filename, files.id, sum(in_trash) AS s, count(*) AS c 
FROM items, files, item_files_map 
WHERE items.id = item_files_map.item_id AND files.id = item_files_map.file_id 
GROUP BY files.id
HAVING s = c
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work fine (however with WHERE s=c istead of sum = c).

Comment: The idea is very good but unfortunately the performance starts to suffer on tables having several thousand items. Because of the inner `GROUP BY`, MySQL query planner cannot do much optimization on it.

Comment: The outer `SELECT` is not needed, get rid of it. Append `HAVING s = c` to the inner query, change `filename` to `files.id` in the `GROUP BY` clause (`id` is PK, `filename` is probably not indexed) and you have a nice query. Then, when it starts lagging use my answer ;-)

Comment: My answer was wrong, I deleted it. Keep the rest from my previous comment.